# Xml conversion from one structure to another structure in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am having an requirement where i need to convert old xml to new xml here are my both 
old XML:

```
<Comments>
    <checkintext>
        <bpcheckdeviated>true</bpcheckdeviated>
        <task>
            <id>CS-2213</id>
            <bugtrackid></bugtrackid>
            <name>Cannot delete the picking lists (lines)</name>
            <version>6.2.1000.4051</version>
            <sprint>17.8</sprint>
            <project>Cs2213_Prd_DelPickIssue</project>
            <area>Production</area>
            <taskstatus>Closed</taskstatus>
        </task>
        <text>1. Issue with delete of picking list is fixed. The creation of picking list was creating mess in the inventTrans. This is also fixed.</text>
        <notes>
            <note>
               <section>Info</section>
               <component>axs</component>
               <text>hello</text> 
            </note>
        <notes> 
    </checkintext>
</Comments>
```

and here is how the new xml should like but data must be same:

```
<Details>
    <CheckBestPractices>true</CheckBestPractices>
    <Task Id="Cs-2213">
        <Name>Cannot delete the picking lists (lines)</Name>
        <Version>6.2.1000.4051</Version>
        <Sprint>17.8</Sprint>
        <Project>Cs2213_Prd_DelPickIssue</Project>
        <Area>Production</Area>
        <Status>Closed</Status>
        <BugTrackId/>
    </Task>
    <Text><![CDATA[Issue with delete of picking list is fixed. The creation of picking list was creating mess in the inventTrans. This is also fixed.]]> </Text>
    <SpecialNotes>
        <Note>
            <Component/>
            <Section></Section>
            <Text><![CDATA[ <here your text> ]]> </Text>
        </Note>
    </SpecialNotes>
</Details>
```

How can i do this is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

Comment: can u please tell me the process i am having no idea about xslt

Comment: Neither do I, but there will be countless tutorials when you put it into google.